# Getting GStreamer latencies

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to obtain latency stats for my GStreamer pipeline following documentation: [Link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/tracing.html?gi-language=c#try-it) However on my Yocto Linux machine running gst-launch-1.0 version 1.22.5 I can't seem to get any GST_TRACERS output even though pipeline runs normally.

When I try same exact commands on my other Ubuntu Linux machine with GStreamer gst-launch-1.0 version 1.20.3 I can get debug/tracers output normally.

Is there something system-related I need to enable/alter in order to get the GStreamer logging output?

Command I tried on both is following:

```
GST_DEBUG="GST_TRACER:7" GST_TRACERS=latency gst-launch-1.0 \
audiotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! audioconvert ! volume volume=0.7 ! \
autoaudiosink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build `gstreamer` with `coretracers` enabled.

To do this in `meson` use the extra parameter `-Dgstreamer:coretracers=enabled`.

You can verify your build has `coretracers` enabled using the following command:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep coretracers
```

If coretracers is not installed no output will be displayed, if it is installed you should get something like this:

```
coretracers:  factories (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  latency (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  leaks (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  log (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  rusage (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  stats (GstTracerFactory)
```